# May I ask game identifcation questions on meta?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, game-identification

I know that I can't ask on the main site, as per the tag definition of [game-identification](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-identification).

If I can remember some description of a game, may I ask it here? If not, does anyone know a non S.E site where it would be on-topic?

Comment: I lot of people recommend the [Reddit Tip of my Joystick](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmyjoystick/) for Game Identification from memory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No**. Meta is specifically for questions about Arqade. You are more than welcome to ask in [The Bridge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) though.

Comment: Thanks for that :-) as active as I have been on other SE sites, I have not yet tried chat; seems like time to stat :-)

Comment: @Mawg - also, check out or wiki on [Game Identification](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/game-identification/info), we list a few communities that take these questions, and we have a guide to gathering as much info as you can to help you in your search too :-)